# Есть массив с 10 элементов?

Tags: javascript

Есть массив с 10 элементов.
Как найти сумму двух элементов массива x = [] 
И вывести массив с новыми элементами, элементами которого есть суммы двух соседних элементов

```js
function Create() {
  x = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var j = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
    x[i] = j;
  }
}
Create()
document.write(x);
```

Comment: В пустом массиве `  x = []` нет элементов, значит код бессмысленный.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sums = [];
for (var i = 0; i < x.length - 1; i++)
  sums[i] = x[i] + x[i + 1];
document.write("<br>");
document.write(sums);
```